# "Inserted disabled" while upgrading Sun Sparc t5120 memory

Tags: hardware, installation, sun, sparc

I'm trying to upgrade a Sun t5120 server from 4GB to 8GB of RAM memory:

I followed all the steps described on the section "Upgrade Memory Configuration With Additional FB-DIMMs" "[Sun SPARC Enterprise T5120 and T5220 Servers Service Manual](http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/820-2181-13/820-2181-13.pdf)"

When I run showfaults command from ALOM I'm getting always this output:

```
sc> showfaults
Last POST Run: Wed Jul 29 09:50:21 2009

Post Status: Passed all devices
  ID FRU               Fault
   1 /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR0/CH0/D0 SP detected fault: /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR0/CH0/D0 Inserted disabled
   2 /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR0/CH1/D0 SP detected fault: /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR0/CH1/D0 Inserted disabled
   3 /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR1/CH0/D0 SP detected fault: /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR1/CH0/D0 Inserted disabled
   4 /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR1/CH1/D0 SP detected fault: /SYS/MB/CMP0/BR1/CH1/D0 Inserted disabled
```

What does it means this message? How I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you solve the problem in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this link can help you clarify what kind of error is occurring.
http://docs.sun.com/source/820-4445-10/chapter1.html

The document referenced above appears to be [**here**](http://docs.sun.com/source/820-4445-13/index.html) now